# Do I need an RSA private key in order to upload files using SFTP with the SSH.NET library for .NET?

Tags: ssh, sftp, rsa

Is it essential that I have an rsa private key or is it possible to use a username and password?

I ask because of [this explanation for the SSH.NET library for .NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET#usage):

> “Establish a SFTP connection using both password and public-key authentication:”

Is it necessary or can I use one or the other?

My question is: is it **required** that I have a private key in order to upload files to a server using SFTP or will a username/password suffice?

Comment: My take is that since the wiki header your code sample is under is labled "Multi-Factor Authentication" that they are showing you how to create a connection using multiple authentication methods at once. from what I'm seeing in the doc for the `ConnectionInfo` class though, its not really clear that it is or isn't required, leading me to believe that the requirement, if there is one, is set by the server itself. Give it a try with a known SFTP server that supports just password auth and see if it works with just password., https://doc.neonkube.com/T_Renci_SshNet_ConnectionInfo.htm

Comment: It is not an either/or situation but based on what the managers of the SFTP server has setup. Some places allow password and public-key. Others are just password or public-key. It all depends on the settings put in place by what the managers of the SFTP server have set up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SFTP server decides what authentication methods it will accept.
If it requires a key you need a key. If allows userid/password then that can be used.
It may even require 2 authentication methods to be used (MFA situation).

So there is no "one size fits all" answer. It totally depends on the SFTP server you are using.